# Videojs - testing if video is working

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, automation, casperjs, video.js

We have got videos on our websites that are running using VideoJS and are loaded from an external CDN. How can I check using Selenium or SlimerJS + CasperJS or any other way if a video that video:

1. Has loaded from CDN (no 404 err.)
2. Has loaded in the browser
3. Is running (suppose autorun is triggered)
4. There are no errors / exceptions (for example - "To view this video please enable JavaScript...")

Thanks for any help

[image: For example - Exception no video]